Different ways of passing a variable by reference?
I want to pass a variable to a function and have the function change the value.
I know I can do this as an object but am wondering if there is some way to do this that I haven't thought of.
This is what I want to do, but it doesn't work the way I want of course:
function test1(vari) {
    vari = 2;
}
var myvar1 = 1;
test1(myvar1);
console.log(myvar1); //1

This works, but I don't really want to make all the variables objects:
function test2(vari) {
    vari.val = 2;
}
var myvar2 = { val: 1 };
test2(myvar2);
console.log(myvar2.val); //2

This also works, but not an acceptable solution:
function test3(vari) {
    eval(vari + ' = 2;');
}
var myvar3 = 1;
test3('myvar3');
console.log(myvar3); //2

Is there a better option than these?
Updated
A better example of what I would like to do:
function test5(vari, onblur) {
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += `<input id="ctl_${vari}" type="text" value="${vari}">`;
    el = document.getElementById(`ctl_${vari}`);
    el.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
        vari = e.target.value; //Doesn't update original variable
        onblur(e);
    });
    return el;
}
var myvar5 = 'test';
var ele = test5(
    myvar5,
    function(e) {
        //Could set myvar5 = e.target.value but not wanting to do this for every single field
        console.log(myvar5);
    }
);


There is no way to pass variables by reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

This seems very much like an XY problem.

What's wrong with myVar = myFunc(myVar); where myFunc() returns the new value?

@TangentiallyPerpendicular, this is just a simplified example, but in my I can't use return.

@johna then you can't do it; JavaScript simply has no such facility.

@johna Please tell us more about your constraints. What is your actual problem? "I don't really want to make all the variables objects" - why not? How many variables are there? Put them all in one object. "Is there a better option than these?" - closures and callbacks might seem more natural, but your simplified examples gives us no indication of whether you'd be able to use them.

My problem is converting some old procedural UX code written in another language 35 years ago to JavaScript with minimal changes. Inside my function a control gets added to a page and, for example, event handlers get created and listen for blur and at that point the variable value gets updated. That is still very simplified and a lot more happens but more than worth going into. The answer is I can't do exactly what I want and need to look at one of the alternatives. Eval is actually working just fine but ugly.

Where is the variable declared, is it global? Do you actually need to pass different variables into the function?

Variables are in a different scope.
I have made another example and updated my post to better reflect use case.

Like already stated in the comments, you cannot pass-by-reference in JavaScript. All arguments passed to a function are pass-by-value. This is even the case for objects. Though you can mutate an object passed as argument, you cannot re-assign it (making it pass-by-value). See: Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language? and Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"? (also applies to JavaScript) for details.
What you can do is return multiple values using an array:
function test(a, b) {
  return [a + b, a - b];
}

let a = 5, b = 2;
[a, b] = test(a, b);

The final value for a is 7 and b is 3.
Note that the semicolon after let a = 5, b = 2; is required, otherwise it's executed as let a = 5, b = 2[a, b] = test(a, b); Which in this case results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'b' before initialization".
However in your specific scenario you could simply pass the desired value to the onblur function as an argument to avoid myvar5 = e.target.value in every function definition.
function test5(vari, onblur) {
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += `<input id="ctl_${vari}" type="text" value="${vari}">`;
    const el = document.getElementById(`ctl_${vari}`);
    el.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
        onblur(e, e.target.value);
    });
    return el;
}

// best matching the question code
var myvar5 = 'test';
var ele = test5(myvar5, function(e, myvar5) {
    console.log(myvar5);
});

// probably preferable given the current question code
var ele = test5('test', function(e, value) {
    console.log(value);
});


Looks like I am going with handling updating of the value in the blur handlers as that is the cleanest way of doing it.

This might not be what you are looking for, but maybe try something like:
function test1(vari) {
    return vari += 2;
}

var myvar1 = test1(myvar1);

console.log(myvar1);


My examples were just simplified examples, but in my I can't use return.

Do you mean that for your project, you can't use return as it doesn't fit or that there is an error when you try to use it?

It doesn't fit.

In JS, only object element's are passed by reference.
So don't expect to be able to do it with a simple variable.
However, since all variables belong to the window object,
you can treat it like that, but it's the worst idea of ​​the century.


function fx(varName)
  {
  window[varName]++;
  }

var myVar = 5;
fx('myVar');
console.log( myVar ); // 6




"objects are passed by reference." - no, they aren't. They might be reference values, but they're still passed by value.

@Bergi right, I have reformulated this sentence.

Second worse? eval would be worse, right?

I hadn't thought of this option and although it is not good practice it is better than eval so thanks for your answer. Should note that this will only get global variables.
